# Проблема с масштабированием по центру в Яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем привет, получил такую задачку, что нужно сделать масштабирование только по центру, это пример. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-yamps-g5sr1?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js, Нужно чтобы где бы не находился курсор мышки, он все равно масштабировал карту по центру, по метке, как например у https://taxi.yandex.com/ru_am/. Пробовал создать функцию на onWheel, но для touchpad работает некорректно, так как touchpad слишком чувствителен.